# How to automatically make relationships in an asset without a transaction processor function?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

As the title says, I am trying to make relationships between two Assets and I don't want the need for an extra transaction as I would like the relationship to form automatically when I create the Asset.
For instance, I am trying to create multiple cargos that will be shipped under one shipment. Hence, I would like the relationship to form on both sides automatically so that when I create a Cargo (CARGO_001) and link it to a Shipment (SHIP_001), I can also check from the Shipment Get API to obtain a list of cargos it is carrying. However, my current solution does not automatically generate the relationships on both sides but only on one side, the cargo side, when I create the cargo.

Here is my code in my .cto model file,

```
asset Cargo identified by cargoId {
  o String cargoId
  o ProductType type
  o ShipmentStatus status
  o Long quantity
  o GpsReading origin optional
  o TemperatureReading[] temperatureReadings optional
  o GpsReading[] gpsReadings optional
  o ToppleReading[] toppleReadings optional
  o LuxReading[] luxReadings optional
  o Boolean temperatureViolation default=false
  o Boolean toppleViolation default=false
  o Boolean boxOpened default=false
  o Integer tempcount default=0
  o Boolean previousViolation default=false
  --> Contract contract
  --> Shipment shipment optional
  o CargoPacked cargoPacked optional
  o CargoPickup cargoPickup optional
  o CargoLoaded cargoLoaded optional
  o CargoReceived cargoReceived optional
}

asset Shipment identified by shipmentId {
  o String shipmentId
  --> Cargo[] cargo optional
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a transaction which adds the Cargo asset and links it to the Shipment asset instead of using the standard POST request (if using REST) or "create new asset" (when using Playground)

Comment: I guess that could work but the code wont be clean, having two things that does almost the same thing. However, it's not like the front end would see it, only the developers will see it, so I guess it works as well. Thanks.